# How to prevent Excel UserForm from shrinking/expanding autonomously?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

My Excel UserForms contain a variety of objects, including text boxes, combo boxes, radio buttons, etc. The UserForm and the objects on the UserForm shrink and expand when my laptop is on a docking station and the VBA window is open on a larger monitor.

When I access the UserForm editor from the Forms tab in VBA, I can drag the UserForm resize handles and the objects in the UserForm will immediately snap back to their original state, but I want to do this programmatically so that the end user will not deal with shrunken/expanded UserForms.

I have tried resizing the UserForm upon opening (UserForm_Initialize), but it seems as if the shrinking/expanding takes place while the UserForm is not active, meaning that my UserForm resizing only acts to return the UserForm to its shrunken/expanded state and not its original state.

```
Sub UserForm_Initialize()

 Call ResizeUserform(Me)

End Sub

Sub ResizeUserform(UserForm_Name As Object)

 UserForm_Name.Width = UserForm_Name.Width + 0.001
 UserForm_Name.Width = UserForm_Name.Width - 0.001

 UserForm_Name.Height = UserForm_Name.Height + 0.001
 UserForm_Name.Height = UserForm_Name.Height - 0.001

End Sub
```

Comment: Forms don't normally shrink or expand autonomously - quite the contrary, making a "reactive" UI in MSForms is an absolute nightmare, *because* the UI framework doesn't help with layout whatsoever. Is the form maximized? What is the `BorderStyle`?

Comment: You can try handling the `Resize` event and see if you can absolute-position each control in there (e.g. `Me.TextBox1.Left = Me.Width - RightMargin - Me.TextBox1.Width`, etc.)... good luck!

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I have tried both "None" and "Single" for BorderStyle, and it seemed to have no effect on the shrinking/expanding. Also, I don't give the user the option to resize the form, so it should always be maximized.

Comment: Having a maximized form *is* giving the option to resize: all one needs is... a second monitor with a different size. The form *should* fire its `Resize` event when it is moved to another monitor and resized.

Comment: Either you handle `Resize` and make the form look nice regardless of what monitor size it's displayed on, ....or you make it *not* maximized - that way it'll always be the same size, regardless of monitor size.

Comment: Can't test this, nor do i remember exactly what happens, but problems abound when the monitors setup like this. Good luck and sorry I have no solution, but there may be difficult problems with this dual monitor setup.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon it seems that the easiest solution for me would be to make the form not maximized, but I don't know how to control this.

Comment: Hit F4 in the designer to bring up the properties; select the form itself, one of the properties is controlling this.

Comment: I don't see anything in the UserForm properties menu that could be responsible for maximizing the UserForm. It appears that the only properties that change when the userform shrinks/expands is the Height and Width of the form. The textboxes and buttons keep the same Height and Width properties (despite becoming smaller) because these values appear to be defined relative to the size of the UserForm. When I resize the UserForm back to its original Height and Width, all elements inside the UserForm appeared as they did before the shrinking/expanding.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel VBA Userform editor keeps resizing by itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65536265/excel-vba-userform-editor-keeps-resizing-by-itself)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't leave your form's dimensions ambiguous or prone to logic circularity (i.e. as a function of itself); set them up before loading/showing.

i.e.:

```
   'where XX and YY are integer constants:
   With YourFormName
        .width=XX
        .height=YY
        .show
    end with
```

If you **absolutely** need to incur in circular statements, do it indirectly by storing your calculated variable in a global/local variable, and then proceed to declare its properties (i.e. YourFormName.width=variable)

Good luck!.

Comment: This ended up being the best (and easiest) of all the solutions I tried. For each UserForm, I hardcode the height and width at the beginning of the UserForm_Initialize routine. This works on different monitors with different resolutions.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue, ever time the program opened the Login user form would be smaller than the last time. It only did it on my lap top with extra monitors. I finally used

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
   With Userform
      .Width = Application.Width * 0.3
      .Height = Application.Height * 0.6    
   End With
End Sub
```

in the userforms code and it kind of stopped meaning it no longer showed the user the change but if I open the VBA it had changed size on the Height and Width but since it was only in the VBA and the user didn't have to try and enter a password in a mini box its fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. The only thing that worked for me was going into the Advanced Options of Excel and checking the box, "Disable hardware graphics acceleration." I wasted several hours trying to find this. I hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

Don't make the form maximized. "Maximized" means you *don't* know at design-time what the size of the form will be, because you're making that depend on what monitor size it's being displayed in.

Larger monitor = larger maximized form, that's by design.

If you don't want the form to resize automatically when it's displayed in a different-size monitor, then don't maximize it.

---

Alternatively, handle the form's `Resize` event, and programmatically move each control where it needs to be relative to the bottom-right edge. Note, that's tricky and extremely annoying code to write, especially if the form is any kind of complicated. Much simpler to just not have a maximized form.

Answer (score 0):

this operation can also be done with **a loop**. I used the button to increase and decrease the height of userform. I created a loop and assigned it to the button.At the same time there was a nice animation.
You set a height value, when the button is pressed, the userform becomes longer if the height is less than this value, and the userform becomes shorter if it is larger.
Codes:

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
Dim X, d, yuk, mak As Integer
For X = 1 To 100
DoEvents
If e = 0 Then
d = d + 10
yuk = 242
mak = 342
Else
d = d - 10
yuk = 345
mak = 245
End If
UserForm2.Height = yuk + d
If UserForm2.Height >= mak And e = 0 Then GoTo 10
If UserForm2.Height <= mak And e = 1 Then GoTo 20
Next
10 CommandButton4.Caption = "<"
e = 1
ListBox1.ListIndex = 0
ScrollBar1_Change
Exit Sub
20 CommandButton4.Caption = ">"
e = 0
ListBox1.ListIndex = 0
End Sub
```

It's video :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1LCxgQGy9tU

[Source and Example file here](https://merkez-ihayat.blogspot.com/2015/11/userform-with-scrollbar.html)

Comment: Try to avoid so called *Spaghetti code* with `GoTo` commands inherited from former BASIC times - that's not the state of the art, as you risk losing track of any inner structure; only error handling is commonly accepted by such routines. BTW `Dim X, d, yuk, mak As Integer` will declare only `mak` as `Integer`, the neglected  variables `X`, `d`,`yuk` are interpreted as `Variant` as they aren't declared expressly as `Integer`: MS Help states: *"If you don't specify a data type or object type, and there is no Def_type_ statement in the module, the variable is **Variant** by default."*

Answer (score 0):

Imo this problem duplicates the StackOverflow post [Excel VBA Userform editor keeps resizing by itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65536265/excel-vba-userform-editor-keeps-resizing-by-itself).

1. Imo it is correctly answered by [the winning answer on that page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65536526).
2. The solution: check the "Optimize for compatibility" option in File|Options|General|User Interface options, and restart Excel.
3. I would post the screenshot, but I don't yet have enough whuffie (if this were a radio station, I'd say I'm a longtime listener, first time caller!).

happy Excelling :-)