# Excel VBA Userform editor keeps resizing by itself

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have made a userform in Excel and saved it. Every now and then when I open up the editor, the form has been resized by itself. When I click in the bottom right corner of the form to resize it, it automatically pops back to the original intended size (see the `GIF` below).

This also affects the forms at runtime. Is this a bug needed to be fixed by Microsoft, or is there some sort of auto-resizing setting that I can disable?

I do have this initialization code with the hardcoded intended size:

```vba
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.Width = 402.6
    Me.Height = 430.8
    
    Me.StartUpPosition = 0
    Me.Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * Me.Width)
    Me.Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * Me.Height)
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like DPI awareness, but I wasn't aware VBA Userforms supported that. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/ddpi/handle-high-dpi-and-dpi-scaling-in-your-office-solution

Comment: I tried setting the [Optimize for compatibility](https://analyse-it.com/blog/2018/5/microsoft-windows-office-2016-multiple-monitor-dpi-awareness-and-analyse-it-s-missing-user-interface) option. But with this setting on, excel crashes immediately when I try to resize a form.

Comment: Did you take out your code when you did that?

Comment: well now it does not crash anymore. Let's see if this works. No, I did not take out my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @braX for pointing me to the right direction. It seems to be a [DPI awareness issue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-support-for-high-definition-displays-6720ca0e-be59-41f6-b629-1369f549279d?ns=excel&version=90&syslcid=1033&uilcid=1033&appver=zxl900&helpid=148371&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us).

The solution for me was to check the `Optimize for compatibility` option, and restart Excel.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me, the below worked. You may like to check;
https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/userforms-shrink-on-successive-openings-of-an-excel-file.1078705/
Adding the following to the userform code at least kept the display right.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With frm40_Overview1
        Height = 600
        Width = 800
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Cheers